# Injecting validators in FluentValidation

Tags: c#, fluentvalidation

This is my setup:

```
public class BusinessUnitIdValidator : AbstractValidator<string>
{
    public BusinessUnitIdValidator(IConfigSettings configSettings)
    {
        LovFile buidLovFile = configSettings.BuidLovFile;
        When(x => buidLovFile.IsValidationRequired.Equals("true", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase),
            () =>
            {
                RuleFor(x => x).Must((buid) => IsValidBusinessUnitId(buidLovFile, buid)).WithMessage(ValidationResultConstants.INVALID_BUSINESS_UNIT_ID);
            });
    }
}

public CreateCustomerRequestValidator(IValidator<string> _businessUnitIdValidator)
{
    RuleFor(x => x).NotNull();
    RuleFor(x => x.BusinessUnitId).NotNull().WithMessage(ValidationResultConstants.BUSINESS_UNIT_ID_SHOULD_NOT_BE_NULL);
    RuleFor(x => x.BusinessUnitId).SetValidator(_businessUnitIdValidator);
}
```

This is another validator that I like to unit test. I'm mocking the  behavior of BusinessUnitIdValidator so it should just pass without any issues.

```
List<ValidationFailure> validationFailures = new List<ValidationFailure>();
ValidationResult validationResultMock = new ValidationResult(validationFailures);
Mock<IValidator<string>> _businessUnitIdValidatorMock = new Mock<IValidator<string>>();
_businessUnitIdValidatorMock.Setup(b => b.Validate(It.IsAny<string>())).Returns(validationResultMock);
validator = new CreateCustomerRequestValidator(_businessUnitIdValidatorMock.Object);

CreateCustomerRequest createCustomerRequest = GetCreateCustomerRequest();

//Act
var validationResult = validator.Validate(createCustomerRequest);
```

I'm getting an null reference exception:

```
System.NullReferenceException
  HResult=0x80004003
  Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
  Source=FluentValidation
  StackTrace:
   at FluentValidation.Validators.ChildValidatorAdaptor.Validate(PropertyValidatorContext context) in /home/jskinner/code/FluentValidation/src/FluentValidation/Validators/ChildValidatorAdaptor.cs:line 56
   at FluentValidation.Internal.PropertyRule.<Validate>d__65.MoveNext() in /home/jskinner/code/FluentValidation/src/FluentValidation/Internal/PropertyRule.cs:line 282
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.SelectManySingleSelectorIterator`2.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereEnumerableIterator`1.MoveNext()
   at FluentValidation.AbstractValidator`1.Validate(ValidationContext`1 context) in /home/jskinner/code/FluentValidation/src/FluentValidation/AbstractValidator.cs:line 115
   at Customer.UnitTests.Libraries.CustomerModelValidators.CreateCustomerRequestValidatorTests.ShouldPass()
```

My integration tests are working fine though.

Thanks,
Arun

Comment: What i is the return type of `public CreateCustomerRequestValidator(IValidator<string> _businessUnitIdValidator)` method? there should be compile time error in this situation.

Comment: @FaridImranov.. that's a constructor. All validations happen in the constructor.

Comment: Just to clarify.. CreateCustomerRequestValidator is a different validator and I'm only showing the constructor here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer to this: I was mocking the incorrect version of the Validate method.

```
_businessUnitIdValidatorMock.Setup(b => b.Validate(It.IsAny<ValidationContext>())).Returns(validationResultMock);
```

Thanks,
Arun